# How do I make this multiple insert construction run faster. A function and two selects

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, sql-insert

The story:

I need to put random variables in the place table, and make 200 000 records, but these PIDfrom and PIDto are foriegn keys from the Place table which already has 200 000 records.

When I run this code I get only 5000 records in something like 15 minutes which is unacceptable. I am using SQL server 2008 R2. Searched online what to do, I couldn't figure it out. Really need help with this, I just done know how to optimize it so it's presentable. I am thankful for all suggestions.

```
 while @i < 200000
 begin
 insert into Item( IIT, Weight, PIDfrom, PIDto) values ('IIT'+ cast(@i as varchar(10)), rand ()*10000, 
 (select top 1 PID from Place
 order by NEWID()),
 (select top 1 PID from Place
  order by NEWID()) )
  set @i = @i + 1 
 end
```

Comment: Do you want 125,000 random entries with duplicates, or do you want 125,000 unique random entries?

Comment: I'd go with Gordon's answer. For further reading: [Selecting Rows Randomly from a Large Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You want two random places to combine.  Let do this as using a `join`:

```
with p1 as (
      select p.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from place)
     , p2 as (
      select p.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from place)

select 'ITT' + cast(row_number() over (order by (select null)) as varchar(255)),
       rand(checksum(newid))) * 10000,
       p1.pid, p2.pid
from p1 join
     p2
     on p1.seqnum = p2.seqnum;
```

For performance, you might use a temporary table and a `join`:

```
select p.*, row_number() over (order by newid)) as seqnum1,
       row_number() over (order by newid)) as seqnum2
into #tempp
from places p;

create index idx_tempp_seqnum1 on #tempp(seqnum1);
create index idx_tempp_seqnum2 on #tempp(seqnum2);

select 'ITT' + cast(row_number() over (order by (select null)) as varchar(255)),
       rand(checksum(newid))) * 10000,
       p1.pid, p2.pid
from #tempp p1 join
     #tempp p2
     on p1.seqnum1 = p2.seqnum2;
```